# Where to filter 'Deleted' rows in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have logical deletes in our database, and each table has a 'Deleted' flag, which is a nullable datetime field.

```
Deleted DATETIME NULL
```

In our queries, I use the pattern:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b 
   ON b.id = a.pkid
   AND b.deleted IS NULL
INNER JOIN TableC c
   ON c.id = b.pkid
   AND c.deleted IS NULL
WHERE a.deleted IS NULL
```

Is that more efficient than:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b 
   ON b.id = a.pkid
INNER JOIN TableC c
   ON c.id = b.pkid
WHERE a.deleted IS NULL
AND b.deleted IS NULL
AND c.deleted IS NULL
```

I understand that when Left joins come into it, the parrent changes. I am talking about INNER joins here.

I think the first is more efficient, because the way the server does the query. I can't find the page I saw about the stages... i.e First the Joins, then the Where, then the Order, then the select... But the first example would limit the data, and THEN the where gets fired, so the WHERE is covering less data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also add the predicate on a to the first join ...

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
   JOIN TableB b 
      ON b.id = a.pkid
         AND a.deleted IS NULL
         AND b.deleted IS NULL
   JOIN TableC c
      ON c.id = b.pkid
         AND c.deleted IS NULL
```

but, in general, it is not reliable to count on one specific syntactical approach to generate better or worse performance than another.  The query optimizer can do some strange things, often turning two vastly different queries into the same plan.   Try them both and look at the query plans to see what happens.